# Invoking a method from a c# class in an ASP.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm following a youtube tutorial inorder to display images from my sql database intoa grid view and I pretty much followed the coding step by step. However I seem to have  a problem when creating a webform and calling the a method from a public class I just created into the webform's page_load method. I'm not sure what's wrong

Here's what my class looks like :

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Gender { get; set; }
    public String Photo { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDataAccessLayer
{

    public  static List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        List<Employee> listEmployees = new List<Employee>();

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBSC"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EmployeeID"]);
                employee.Name = rdr["Name"].toString();
                employee.Gender = rdr["Gender"].toString();
                employee.Photo = rdr["PhotoPath"].toString();

                listEmployees.Add(employee);
            }
        }
        return listEmployees;
    }
}
```

in the webform's codepage this is what I'm trying to do:

```
protected void page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   EmployeeDataAccessLayer.GetAllEmployees();
}
```

however I'm getting an error in the " EmployeeDataAccessLayer.GetAllEmployee();" that says that the later line does not exist in the context

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you are missing the 's' from the end of EmployeeDataAccessLayer.GetAllEmployees()??

Comment: @Sara, are you sure ? Did you copy and paste from your project to your question ? If yes, you missed the 's' inside the page_Load(). Otherwise please update your question.

Comment: @Heslacher right I just fixed that but the thing is it still doesn't exist in the context

Comment: @Sara Are both classes, the webform and the EmployeeDataAccessLayer inside the same solution ?

Comment: @Heslacher yes they are

Comment: And if you type inside your page_Load the word EmployeeDataAccessLayer, then a dot does intellisense show your method ?

Comment: Can you post the actual exception?

Comment: No it doesnt show the method

Comment: Missing the required `using` statement perhaps? Does the `EmployeeDataAccessLayer` exist in a different namespace to your webform?

Comment: So after typing your Methodname after the dot you get a red line. Hoover over the line right click and use 'Resolve' to add the desired using.

Comment: Is the file containing your class(EmployeeDataAccessLayer) included in the project?

Comment: They all are under the same name space, and I'm doing what @heslacher said but there is not resolve

Comment: @st4hoo yes it's in the project

Comment: Perhaps a clean/build solution is in order?

Comment: on a side note: you are returning `List<Employee>` from `GetAllEmployees`, but you are not retrieving it in the call you are showing. Maybe you should include your form code as well to help finding the issue here.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste as in the source code from the .aspx file?

Comment: Can't hurt, but is all your webform's code logic contained within the aspx-file or is there a seperate code-behind cs(or aspx.cs)-file? I meant the file containing the code, not necessarily the mark up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the code file in app_code folder to make it directly accessible to pages. Also you have to change the Build Action to `Complile` from `Content`

Right click the code file in app_code and select properties from context menu, then change the Build Action.

[image]